# « I know not how it was » [negative. cl. w/o do-support] : les outils d'un style ?

Tags: négation, mode-grammatical, comparaison-de-langues, style-de-rédaction, registre-soutenu

> During the whole of a dull, dark, and soundless day in the autumn of
>   the year, when the clouds hung oppressively low in the heavens, I had
>   been passing alone, on horseback, through a singularly dreary tract of
>   country; and at length found myself, as the shades of the evening drew
>   on, within view of the melancholy House of Usher. **I know not how it
>   was**—but, with the first glimpse of the building, a sense of
>   insufferable gloom pervaded my spirit. [...]
>
> ---
>
> Pendant toute la journée d’automne, journée fuligineuse, sombre et
>   muette, où les nuages pesaient lourd et bas dans le ciel, j’avais
>   traversé seul et à cheval une étendue de pays singulièrement lugubre,
>   et enfin, comme les ombres du soir approchaient, je me trouvai en vue
>   de la mélancolique Maison Usher. **Je ne sais comment cela se fit**, —
>   mais, au premier coup d’œil que je jetai sur le bâtiment, un sentiment
>   d’insupportable tristesse pénétra mon âme. [...]
>
> [ Edgar Allan Poe, [*The Fall of the House of Usher*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Tales_(Poe)/The_Fall_of_the_House_of_Usher), 1839, avec la [traduction](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Chute_de_la_maison_Usher) de Charles Baudelaire, je souligne ]

Une proposition négative de ce type sans auxiliaire est [valide mais archaïque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) en langue anglaise (*negated clause with finite lexical verb without do-support*) ; le sens est identique à celui de *I don't know* soit *je ne sais pas*...

---

- En français, ce style littéraire, cet archaïsme, ce registre, est-il
  suffisamment réalisé par le seul aménagement des particules de
  négation ou requiert-il de surcroît un mode(personnel)/temps
  particulier du verbe, ou leur addition constitue-t-elle un niveau
  distinct, encore plus soutenu, littéraire ou recherché, de ce style ?
- Le pronom ou le mode impersonnel du verbe est-il d'un quelconque
  secours dans ce genre de contexte ; le cas échéant comment se compare le résultat obtenu avec ce qui précède ?

---

Peut-on de préférence comparer et analyser à l'aide d'un autre exemple de traduction pour voir si on a toujours le même procédé.

Comment: Je ne vois pas quelle tournure impersonelle peut convenir ici. Est-ce que ce serait possible de préciser de quoi il serait question ?

Comment: Possiblement qu'on parlait de _se faire (il se fit)_ ou du pronom démons.  _cela_. Probablement qu'on compare _je ne sais pas (comment)_ avec _je ne sais comment cela se fit_ et qu'on essaye de comprendre si on pouvait mettre la barre plus bas pour réaliser le même registre/style...

Comment: Pas tout à fait dans les mêmes contextes : « Je ne comprends pas ce vous dites, *ni ne sais* où vous voulez en venir » — « *Ne savoir* parler qu’une langue est le lot du commun des mortels  ».

Answer (score 1):

In this case "I know not how it was" is saying that the author or teller of the story is saying that he can't explain it, but somehow, looking at this house, there was a pervasive sense of insufferable gloom.  The "I know not how it was" is just that " he doesn't know how to explain it".

:)